# How to identify a element present under specific element with specific place

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest, how to find 'mfrac' is present under 'msup' element within its second child side. (Mfenced is mfenced, when its contains 'mfrac as its descendant, but **only when** mfrac found under second child position of msup, then should convert to '**mo**'.)

- When mfrac is within first child side of 'msup', then 'mfenced' is no
  need to alter.
- When mfrac is within **second child** side of 'msup', then 'mfenced'
  is to convert to '**mo**'
- otherwise 'mfrac' found within 'mfenced', then 'mfenced' is no need
  to alter.

**XML:**

```
<article>
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></mfenced></math>
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><msup><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac><mn>7</mn></msup></mfenced></math>
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><msup><mn>7</mn><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></msup></mfenced></math>
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><msup><mrow><mn>7</mn></mrow><mrow><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></mrow></msup></mfenced></math>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mfenced">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(descendant::mfrac[. is ancestor::msup[1]/*[1]/descendant::*])"><!--checking, whether mfrac not found within first child of 'msup' -->
            <mo><xsl:apply-templates/></mo>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required result:**

```
<article>
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></mfenced></math><!--no need alter, because 'mfrac' found within 'mfenced'-->
<math><mfenced open="(" close=")"><msup><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac><mn>7</mn></msup></mfenced></math><!--no need alter, because 'mfrac' found within first child of 'msup' -->
<math><mo><msup><mn>7</mn><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></msup></mo></math><!--Converted to 'MO', because 'mfrac' is under 2nd child of 'msup' -->
<math><mo><msup><mrow><mn>7</mn></mrow><mrow><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></mrow></msup></mo></math><!--Converted to 'MO', because 'mfrac' is under 2nd child of 'msup' -->
</article>
```

**Error message:**

```
  XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second operand of 'is' (<mn/>, <mn/>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mfenced[
        not(mfrac)
        and (
            msup/mfrac[preceding-sibling::*]
            or msup//mfrac[not(parent::msup)]
        )
    ]">
        <mo><xsl:apply-templates/></mo> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can i have same condition within '**xsl:when**', because some other conditions are given within choose.

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. But my suggestion would be to just make templates for the other conditions that you currently have an `<xsl:when>` for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, plus one.